# How to had a column equals true if an element is present in another request?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am new in SQL Server. As entry I have two tables `footballplayers` and `students` and I would like to do something like this :

```
SELECT 
     name, 
     (SELECT footballplayers.idPersonne = students.idPersonne 
      FROM STUDENTS, footballplayers).Count AS student 
FROM footballplayers
```

It should return a tab with the name of the footballer and a boolean value which say if the person is a student.

Do you have any idea how I can do it ?

Thank you

Comment: An exact answer would be possible if you provide sample data from the `footballplayers` and `students` tables. Regardless, `inner join`ing the two tables should give you what you need as results will only be returned if a match is found (`footballplayers.idPersonne = students.idPersonne`). If you wanted football players that aren't students then you would do a `left join`

Comment: "if an element is present in another request" is implemented with an `EXISTS`. You can use a `CASE` to return a particular value (yes/no, 1/0) depending on a condition. Try mixing these 2 up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a good use for left join, as it would easily show if the person exists in the students table as well.

```
SELECT 
     name
     , CASE
        WHEN students.idPersonne IS NULL THEN 'FALSE'
        ELSE 'TRUE'
        END AS 'IsStudent'
FROM footballplayers 
    LEFT JOIN students ON footballplayers.idPersonne = students.idPersonne
```

Answer (score 3):

SQL Server doesn't have booleans.  Often, 0 and 1 are used.

For this purpose, you would use `exists`:

```
SELECT fp.name, 
       (CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1
                          FROM students s
                          WHERE fp.idPersonne = s.idPersonne
                         )
             THEN 1 ELSE 0
        END) as is_student 
FROM footballplayers fp;
```

Comment: There's great documentary on Amazon Prime  "The Genius of George Boole"  ... I never even considered origin of Boolean Logic.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
Select
    fp.Name
    , Cast(Iif(fp.idPersonne is Null, 0, 1) as Bit) as Student_Status
From FootballPlayers as fp
    Left Outer Join Students as s
        on fp.idPersonne = s.idPersonne
```

"Left Outer Join" will give you all the records in the FootballPlayer table, and if there is a match on idPersonne in the Students table, you'll get that value.  If there's not a match, you'll get a NULL.